# Is it possible for a webpage to change its content based on the button you clicked to get to that page?

Tags: frontend

Let's say there's two buttons on a homepage that both link to the same page. Is there a way to exclusively show a certain part of the page if you click on one button and show a different part if you click the other button?

If this is not an option, would it be possible to store the information of which button is clicked to get to the page?

I'm really quite in the dark on this and barely know how to formulate the questions i am asking, so finding an answer on google is quite difficult. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,sure. Just add different parameter to the link on the buttons e.g. page.html?type=1, page.html?type=2. On the target page read the value of the parameter and modify the page accordingly.